# Normalizing an integer to pass to another value

Tags: c#, math, normalize

I have an integer that updates itself from 0 - 599 which I'm trying to normalize and pass to another variable. My first integer value is just a single int. It isn't in a list or anything.

What I'm trying to do is tie in a color lerp time length based on the length of integer value. This integer value is iterating through a list of meshes to be displayed. It looks like this:

```
int meshNum;
public void AnimateMesh()
{
        if(playAnim)
        {
            meshToChange.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = fluidMesh[meshNum];

            if(meshNum < 599)
                meshNum++;
            else
                meshNum = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            meshNum = 0;
        }
}
```

And my lerp code for the color is this:

```
diffuse_Material.color = Color.Lerp(Color.blue, Color.red, speedCount);
```

What I'm wanting to change speedCount in my lerp method to a variable that is matched with the length of the animation. My lerp isn't always on screen, but the animation is, when I want the lerp to appear, I want to it be the same each time it appears no matter where the animation currently is.

Comment: what do you mean by **normalize** ?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize"..? Can you provide some examples.

Comment: updated my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Color.Lerp` expects a parameter from `0 .. 1`. The simplest way would be to simply give it `(float)meshNum / 599f`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float number = (float)randomizedNumber / 599.0f;
```

since your max value is 599, anyway this color difference would'nt be noticed or event will be rounded since RGB has only 256 values for eash base color.